# How to place squares correctly?

Tags: html, css

I want to achieve this thing:

[I want this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLGhL.png)

so it would be 3 squares next to others, then we have "enter" and next 3 squares.

but my site looks like this for now, despite I have created different divs for 3 squares each.:

[I have this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCeXg.png)

Could you tell me what am I doing wrong and how should I repair it?
Css:

```
*
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header
{
  width: 1920;
  height: 1080px;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin:0;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  background-image:  linear-gradient(180deg, #EFEFEF00 0%, #0F4A37 100%);
}

footer{
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

footer img{
  margin-top: 5px;
  height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
}

.main-nav
{
  float: right;
  color: #000000;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}

.main-nav li
{
  display: inline-block;
}

.main-nav li a
{
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  font: Bold 25px/15px Arial;
  padding: 5px;
}

#logo
{
  margin-top: 10px;
  float: left;
}

#sign a
{
  background-color: #DCDFDE;
  padding: 30px 15px 17px 15px;
  border-top: 3px solid black;
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
  border-left: 3px solid black;
  border-right: 3px solid black;
}

.sociale {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  bottom: 40px;
  left: 10px;
  height: 20px;
}

.sociale>img {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 60px;
  width: 75px;
}

.left h1{
  font-size:30px;
  color: rgb(0, 1, 253);
  width: 700px;
  text-align: justify;
  margin-left: 220px;
}

#ourteam
{
  margin-top: 300px;
  margin-left: 220px;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: rgb(24, 188, 253);
}

#squaresUP div {
    float:right;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-right: 30px;
}
#squaresDOWN div {
    float:right;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 300px;
}
#square1 {  background: #7FC4FD 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;}
#square2 {  background: #7FC4FD 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;}
#square3 {  background: #7FC4FD 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;}
#square4 {  background: #7FC4FD 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;}
#square5 {  background: #7FC4FD 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;}
#square6 {  background: #7FC4FD 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;}
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>DingDog</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css-images/style-authors.css" >
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="row">
      <ul id ="logo"> <img src="css-images/dingdog-logo.png"> </ul>

      <ul class="main-nav">
        <li style="padding-left:10px"><a href="">NEWS FEED</a></li>
        <li style="padding-left:10px"><a href="">ABOUT DINGDOG</a></li>
        <li style="padding-left:10px"><a href="authors.html">AUTHORS</a></li>
        <li style="padding-left:10px"><a href="">CONTACT</a></li>
        <li style="padding-left:10px" id ="sign"><a href="signin.html">SIGN IN</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <section>
      <article>
        <p id="ourteam">Our Team.</p>
        <div class="left">
          <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam dictum nisi ac nunc lobortis auctor. Nam nec congue ex, nec ornare elit. Donec feugiat massa vitae mauris euismod malesuada. Pellentesque iaculis dui felis, sit amet molestie augue scelerisque et. Nullam eget mi neque. Ut maximus enim ac fringilla scelerisque. Quisque sit amet sem semper, rutrum nulla eu, fermentum sapien. I</h1>
        </div>

      </article>
    </section>
    <div id="squaresUP">
      <div id="square1"></div>
      <div id="square2"></div>
      <div id="square3"></div>

    </div>
    <div id="squaresDOWN">
      <div id="square4"></div>
      <div id="square5"></div>
      <div id="square6"></div>
    </div>
  </header>


  <footer>

    <img src="social/instagram.png" />
    <img src="social/twitter-white-logo.png" />
    <img src="social/facebook.png" />
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

I would highly appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should steer clear of using inline styles (if possible). It's a best practice to separate your concerns as much as possible when writing your code to prevent any unforseen inconsistencies and dependencies.

That said,

```css
#squares {
  display: block;
}

.sq-column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: none;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.square {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="squares">
  <div class="sq-column">
    <div class="square">a</div>
    <div class="square">b</div>
    <div class="square">c</div>
  </div>
  <div class="sq-column">
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This solution should work. obviously, you want to adjust your widths and margins. But, essentially you want to create columns which flex in the direction of a row. Each with 3 squares in them with margins between them.

The above can be modified to fit your template.

Comment: But I want these on the right, not on the left. If I write `float: right` then again I have 6 squares in one line.

Answer (score 0):

using basic concepts of [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox):

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

section {
  width: 50%;
}

.description {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

div[id^="squares"] {
  display: flex;
}

div[id^="square-"] {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #7FC4FD;
  margin: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <section class="description">
    <article>
      <p id="ourteam">Our Team.</p>
      <div class="left">
        <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam dictum nisi ac nunc lobortis auctor. Nam nec congue ex, nec ornare elit. Donec feugiat massa vitae mauris euismod malesuada. Pellentesque iaculis dui felis, sit amet molestie augue scelerisque et. Nullam eget mi neque. Ut maximus enim ac fringilla scelerisque. Quisque sit amet sem semper, rutrum nulla eu, fermentum sapien. I</h1>
      </div>
    </article>
  </section>
  <section>
    <div id="squaresUP">
      <div id="square-1"></div>
      <div id="square-2"></div>
      <div id="square-3"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="squaresDOWN">
      <div id="square-4"></div>
      <div id="square-5"></div>
      <div id="square-6"></div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```